# Add user input data to show in a table using react js and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

There are two user input text fields, and i want to show that data in a table using redux.

```
<tbody>
    <tr key={key}>
     <td>
       <TextField
         id="FirstName"
         label="First Name"
         type="name"
         value={this.state.fname}                                           
        />
      </td>
      <td>
       <TextField
         id="LastName"
         label="Last Name"
         type="name"
         value={this.state.lastname}                                            
        />
     </td>
   </tr>
```

Add icon

Comment: Have you tried integrating redux in your application? Have you tried to show user input values in table? Please try yourself and let us know what is not working. So that We can help

Comment: yes but how to save values from input to redux?

Comment: Why do you need to save input values to redux?

Comment: why dont you share your entire code which includes redux part as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the solution,
Firstly To render it on a browser set the default values to your state variables.
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
fname : 'Foo ',
lastname : 'Bar',
}
```

}

```
Now, your code will get the value from state and it will render in DOM as you wanted. And use **defaultValue** in place of Value in input. Attribute 'value' is used when you are setting the values onChange but as you have already declared above in state , use **defaultValue** .
```

Like I have done below :-

```
<TextField
 id="FirstName"
 label="First Name"
 type="name"
 defaultValue={this.state.fname}                                           
  />
```

Comment: This is not solution for OP’s problem. Moreover OP text inputs doesn’t even have event handler functions so how come anything can work just assigning state to value or defaultValue?

Comment: Though, I'm not using redux in dis , because for such a small functionality we don't require Redux , neither there are any API calls and if we talk about event handlers , the person has not used event handlers to set the values again and again , the values are directly called from { this.state} . Like from above , it will render in table the static values I have given , Foo and Bar.

Comment: i wanted to understand the flow so i will proceed in that way to use redx

Comment: For that , you need to write action, reducer for that. Please show all your files here so that we could help you.